# Ruby: How to run irb immediately after running ruby file externally?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, terminal

Is there a way to load a ruby file from terminal, but continue coding dynamically after?

Example:

```
$ ruby some_file.rb

# ... code from source file ...
```

and continue coding from here through terminal (in the same fashion as irb)?

Comment: Are you looking for unix `cat` command ?

Comment: `cat` prints out the text, but it doesn't interpret ruby. And if you're suggesting I use `cat` under `irb`, it won't recognize that command. I'm looking to extend from an external ruby file through irb. Is that possible?

Comment: May be I am not getting what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-r` flag will require a file when starting IRB:

```
irb -r /path/to/file
```

Example:

```
~$ echo "def hello; puts 'Hello, world!'; end" > hello.rb
~$ irb -r ./hello
001> hello
Hello, world!
```

See `man irb`:

```
-r library     Same as `ruby -r'.  Causes irb to load the library using require.
```

Answer (score 1):

Run irb, and load the file from within irb.

```
irb> load "some_file.rb"
```

If you want to do that everytime, then write it in a file named `.irbrc`.

**.irbrc**

```
load "some_file.rb"
```